# Symplectic structure on the space of complexes of holomorphic vector bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E\rightarrow X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over a complex manifold. Denote by $Dol(E)$ the space of holomorphic structures on $E$. Fix any Hermitian metric $h$ on $E$ and denote by $\mathcal{A}(E,h)$ the space of unitary connections of type $(1,1)$. There exists an injective map $Dol(E)\rightarrow \mathcal{A}(E,h)$ given by
$$\bar{\partial}\mapsto D(\bar{\partial},h)$$
where $D(\bar{\partial},h)$ denote the Chern connection of $\bar{\partial}$ and $h$. It is well known that we can endow the space $\mathcal{A}(E,h)$ with a symplectic structure. So $Dol(E)$ inherits as well of a symplectic structure (cf Donaldson's ASD Yang-Mills connections papers).

Denote now by $C(X)$ the space of complexes of holomorphic vector bundles (of maybe fixed length)
$$E^*=0\rightarrow E^0\rightarrow E^1 \rightarrow...$$
on $X$.

Is there a way to endow $C(X)$ with a symplectic structure just like for a single vector bundle? Obviously we can always forget the differentials and write
$$E^*\mapsto \bigoplus_i E^i$$
so that we are back to the first case. But I wonder whether we can have a similar construction on $C(X)$.